# Apache Artemis do not synchronize retain message in cluster mode <message-load-balancing>STRICT</message-load-balancing>

Tags: cluster-computing, activemq-artemis

I have an issue with an Artemis MQTT Cluster (two nodes). The cluster work well but only the retain message isn't synchronized between my two cluster nodes.

I looked a bit around and found [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58744799/apache-mq-artemis-mqtt-retained-message-not-available-for-a-client-that-connec):

`<redistribution-delay>0</redistribution-delay>`

Unfortunately this does not work for me.

To understand and clarify this, I have looked in the [Artemis documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/1.5.3/clusters.html) which states:

> This option only will work for ON_DEMAND **message-load-balancing**.

However, I want to use `STRICT` mode.

Currently I am using apache-artemis-2.11.0 running on two Ubuntu 18 nodes. I use Java version 1.8.0_111 on both nodes.

I configured the artemis cluster and ha-policy in colocated mode:

```xml
<ha-policy>
   <replication>
      <colocated/>
   </replication>
</ha-policy>
```

At the cluster-connections section I use the `<message-load-balancing>STRICT</message-load-balancing>` to build an active-active cluster.

I am a bit confused because everything is working fine except the retain message sync. Do you have any suggestions what my problem could be?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation already indicates what your problem is. You're using `STRICT` as the `message-load-balancing` rather than `ON_DEMAND`. Message redistribution won't work if you use `STRICT`.

Also, it's worth noting that colocated configurations will be deprecated soon so I would recommend against using them.

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it addressed your issue. Thanks!